# C++ detecting keystrokes

Tags: c++, detection, keystrokes

I am trying to use keystrokes to affect my program. For example, I have a program that prints numbers continuously. I want it to stop printing numbers if I enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. How can I do this on C++?

I have read about a number of headers like conio.h but they are not built in the C library. I would like this to be kept as pure C/C++ as possible.

Comment: Are you in Windows or Linux or other? By "stop" do you mean "cancel" or "pause"? Does the program need to continue doing other things after this operation?

Comment: I am using Linux but I would like it to handle Windows as well. I want it cancel for now but would appreciate any references to doing both. Therefore, the program will not be doing anything else after this.

Comment: Normally, `Ctrl-C` would cancel and `Ctrl-S` would pause. Can you clarify what you're wanting to do differently versus these two standard controls?

Comment: Let's say I have a while loop that is printing random numbers. While it is printing, I want to be able to enter Ctrl-E and pause the printing. I want to know if it is possible to leave the standards and make my own customized keystrokes.

Comment: The problem with the answer is that getch is part of conio.h. It is not a header built in the C library. I am wondering if it is possible to do this CLI with a standard C lib.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [GetAsyncKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646293%28VS.85%29.aspx) function for this.

It is there in Winuser.h file

Comment: He didn't say whether he was in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the operating system - hence impossible in 'pure' C/C++.
I fear you have to go with #ifdef SYSTEM_A, ...
Please notice, The languages C/C++ are not aware of any kind of hardware (keyboard in this case), they know streams.

Comment: If I use #ifdef to detect systems, I will still need to determine which headers to use. Are there built in headers to customize keystrokes for windows or linux?